# Не отображается фоновое изображение страницы

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Почему не отображается фоновое изображение страницы?

Цвет фона есть, значит style1.css подключен.

```
body {
 background-image: url(style/images/bg1.jpg);
 background-color: 51ff44;
}

<html>
 <head>
    <title>
        Repairing phones
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style1.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

[image: style.css]

[image: index.html]

Но если сделать фон в index.html, а не в style1.css, то все работает нормально.

[image: 1]

```
<html>
 <head>
 <style>
body {
 background-image: url(style/images/bg1.jpg);
 background-color: 51ff44;
}
</style>
    <title>
        Repairing phones
     </title>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по структуре вашего проекта, это происходит, потому что вы пытаетесь подключить фон-картинку из разных папок. Относительно index.html картинка лежит в `style/images/`, а вот относительно style1.css - в `images/`

Следовательно в style1.css адрес нужно указать так:

```
body {
 background-image: url(images/bg1.jpg);
 background-color: 51ff44;
}
```